# Datepicker onSelect Not Firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a date picker but `onClose` and `onSelect` will not fire. The code is in `document.ready` so i know its initialized.

```
$('#DateRangeTo').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
        inst.dpDiv.css({ marginTop: -input.offsetHeight + 'px', marginLeft: input.offsetWidth + 'px' });
    },
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    startView: 1,
    //daysOfWeekDisabled: "3,4",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    //onClose: function (dateText, inst) { alert("here"); }
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst)
    {
        alert("Working");
    },
    onClose: function (date) {
        var dt = new Date(date);
        alert(dt.getMonth());
    }
});
```

Comment: This could be any number of things, can you create a fiddle so we can see what else is going on?

Answer (score 16):

Must this code work when select a date:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'}).on("changeDate", function (e) {
alert("Working");});
```

Answer (score 3):

Some of the Options you are using are not available in datepicker see http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

And also you are missing `$(function () {});`  See below updated code

```
$(function () {
            $('#DateRangeTo').datepicker({
                beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
                    inst.dpDiv.css({ marginTop: -input.offsetHeight + 'px', marginLeft: input.offsetWidth + 'px' });
                },
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                //startView: 1,
                //daysOfWeekDisabled: "3,4",
                //autoclose: true,
                //todayHighlight: true,
                //onClose: function (dateText, inst) { alert("here"); }
                onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                    alert("Working");
                },
                onClose: function (date) {
                    var dt = new Date(date);
                    alert(dt.getMonth());
                }
            });
        });
```

If still not worked then check for javascript errors in your error console.

Answer (score 2):

The datepicker doesn't trigger the onSelect if there are multiple inputs with the same ID. You shouldn't have multiple elements with the same ID to begin with but the datepicker will show and appear to work and show up. Even some of the other methods like onClose do work but the final onSelect will not