# I want to set a date selected on an html datepicker to show on another datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datepicker

This is my html file:

```
    <div class="col-xs-12">
            <label for="deadline_date" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 contract_form_element">Deadline</label>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 contract_form_element nopadding">
              <input type="date"   class="form-control " id="deadline_date" style="width:200px;"/>
              <label  class="col-xs-12  error_msg" id="deadline_error"><?php if(isset($deadline_date) ) echo form_error('deadline_date'); ?></label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <label for="tender_date" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 contract_form_element">Tender</label>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 contract_form_element nopadding">
              <input type="date" class="form-control"  id="tender_date" style="width:200px;"/>
              <label  class="col-xs-12  error_msg" id="tender_error"><?php if(isset($tender_date) ) echo form_error('tender_date'); ?></label>
            </div>
          </div>
```

This is my jquery code:

```
    $('#deadline_date').datepicker({
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var date = $(this).val();
        alert('on select triggered');
    }
  });
```

The problem is the `alert()` is never called even when i select a date on the `deadline_date id`

Comment: FYI: You have multiple elements using `deadline_error` as the id.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Datepicker onSelect Not Firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21754196/datepicker-onselect-not-firing)

Comment: The problem is you haven't specified which datepicker library/plugin you use. Not all of them have `onSelect`. Ideally you should create a [mcve].

Comment: @devlin carnate please no

Comment: @tao i used normal html date type

Comment: SO, by changing the first `deadline_date` ID - you want to update the `tender_date` to be the same date?

Comment: `datepicker` is a jQuery plugin (an extension). It doesn't exist by default in `jQuery`. Before you can use it you have to load a library (i.e: jQueryUI) or a datepicker plugin (i.e: bootstrap-datepicker) which define that extension. Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same id in your HTML, which is not valid.  The link I posted says that `onSelect` will not work when there are multiple elements with the same id.  Have you verified that this is not your problem by correcting the invalid HTML?

Comment: @devlincarnate i have changed to multiple ids to different names